# Which k should one use to estimate non-symmetric probability through Chebyshev inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I have a problem from a book with µ = 8.4 and σ^2 = 2.52. 
They ask me to find P(6 < X < 11) using the Chebyshev Theorem.

So I'm trying to find the k, but I obtain a value of 1.5119 solving µ - k*σ = 6 for k, and a value of 1.6378 solving µ + k*σ = 11. So it gives two different values of k instead of the same value and I think that this is incorrect since k must have the same absolute value in the two cases. So, how can I find k?

Comment: $k$ is the number of standard deviations.

Comment: They might ask you only to find **a lower bound** of $$P(6<X<11)$$ hence every $k$ such that $$\mu-k\sigma\geqslant6\qquad\mu+k\sigma\leqslant11$$ fits your needs, and of course optimizing $k$ would be a good idea in this context, hence in the end you might want to use $$k=\frac{\min\{\mu-6,11-\mu\}}\sigma$$